# Can I do this with a workflow?

Tags: 2010, workflow, sharepoint-foundation

Let's say that I have a Word template in SharePoint and a user. The user will fill in data in the Word template, via SharePoint, and then save it. The Word template should then generate a new document. This is the general situation.

Now more detailed.
The Word template requires you to fill in the name of an education and the current school academy year. Let's say the education is Applied Computer Science and the school academy year is 2012 - 2013. Upon saving this Word template, a new document is generated and will be saved under a folder titled "Applied Computer Science", which is located inside another folder named "2012 - 2013". The template itself will return to its original state (empty fields for education and year). This is the result I wish to achieve.

Question: 
Does this need a workflow? Can you actually use a workflow to specify that certain fields of a Word document have to be checked and based on those fields, the generated output document gets saved on the correct location?

Just tell me if this is possible or not. And if it's possible, but not with a workflow, then do please tell me how I should be working this out. I'm using SharePoint Foundation 2010. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want to get this information from a word document? I would add additional attributes to the document itsself. You can sort and filter them in the library (and maybe don't need folders).

Comment: Well from example when there are templates for reports regarding a certain education, each template should just be empty. Then a user can fill in the data and mention for what education that report is, and then the report gets sorted in the correct map. The reason I was thinking about putting it in folders was to create a simple overview. Also, most documents in the company here are made in Word, so I don't want to change that too much.

Comment: You could create for each education an own content type with different Word-templates. Maybe, if you only need data like year, name of education, ... you can also work with a simple list (it is much more flexibel than working with word documents), for example you need some reporting afterwards.